# Table width not resizing (pyqt5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am a beginner to Qt and PyQt and am trying to create a table.

I am creating the table as follows:

```
table = QTableWidget(4, 5)
table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tableHeaders)
table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
self.updateTable(table, self.tracks)
table.setFixedHeight(TABLE_FIXED_HEIGHT)
```

With the updateTable function being called every so often to update the table contents.

```
def updateTable(self, table, tracks):
    table.clearContents()
    table.setRowCount(len(tracks))
    for x, track in enumerate(tracks):
        for y, cell in enumerate(track):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(cell)
            item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            table.setItem(x, y, item)
    table.resizeColumnsToContents()
    for col in range(table.columnCount()):
        if table.columnWidth(col) > TABLE_MAXIMUM_COLUMN_WIDTH:
            table.setColumnWidth(col, TABLE_MAXIMUM_COLUMN_WIDTH)
```

This creates a table that is fine, but the width of the table is not adjusting to it's contents, so that the table is too small to display all the columns.

The table seems to adjust to the columns at the start, when they have nothing in them:

[image: Table without data - width correct]

But when the table is populated the width does not resize.

[image: Table with data - width not updated and incorrect]

I don't care about the height, that is fixed.

Any help?

Edit - Here is the layout that the table is contained in

```
titleHBox = QHBoxLayout()
titleHBox.addStretch(1)
titleHBox.addWidget(titleLabel)
titleHBox.addStretch(1)

upperHBox = QHBoxLayout()
upperHBox.addStretch(1)
upperHBox.addLayout(leftVBox)
upperHBox.addWidget(table)    # <-
upperHBox.addLayout(rightVBox)
upperHBox.addStretch(1)
lowerHBox = QHBoxLayout()
lowerHBox.addStretch(1)
lowerHBox.addWidget(loadButton)
lowerHBox.addWidget(saveButton)
lowerHBox.addWidget(spotifyFetchButton)
lowerHBox.addWidget(youtubeFetchButton)
lowerHBox.addWidget(removeButton)
lowerHBox.addStretch(1)
mainVBox = QVBoxLayout()
mainVBox.addLayout(titleHBox)
mainVBox.addLayout(upperHBox)
mainVBox.addLayout(lowerHBox)

self.setLayout(mainVBox)
self.setWindowTitle("Music Converter")
self.show()
```

Edit 2 - Whole code, edited to work standalone https://pastebin.com/X3t1GSfS

Comment: the problem is not in the table, but in the layout that you use to establish the table, it provides a [mcve]

Comment: I added an edit that shows how the layout is set up.

Comment: you could provide a [mcve], have you set a fixed size to the main widget?

Comment: Not the the main widget, no. The only fixed size I have used is the one applied to the height of the table.

Comment: that's not in your code, if you do not provide a [mcve] I can not help you

Comment: I'm new to this, so unless I am missing something, you either mean the QTableWidget which is defined at the top of my post, or the QVBoxLayout titled mainVBox that houses the whole GUI. Can you clarify what I am missing? Please forgive me if I'm being an idiot.

Comment: Have you read the link ?, I want a code that reproduces your problem, does not want to waste time in guessing what is missing and add it, I want a complete code, that is, copy, paste and execute, but at the same time be minimal so that will have to eliminate irrelevant things to the problem, if it gives you lazy to read the link I do not expect you to make an effort to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've read the link, I just didn't think that I needed to upload the entire code, not just the parts that are relevant. Give me a moment as I upload the code to pastebin, redact any api keys or usernames and add some test data to make the program work standalone.

Comment: Ok, done. Not sure how this is "minimal" though, as this includes a lot of unnessasery code (such as my poor first attempt at multithreading)

Comment: show the code in your question, do not place external links for those cases because if they are broken they will make your question unusable.

Comment: for example, it eliminates all of threading, that is not relevant in this question so you would reduce many lines.

Comment: From the stackoverflow question asking help page:
"Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Not only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem."
I'm not just C+Ping my entire code straight into my post. I have included " just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem".

Comment: If you had read [ask] he would have understood correctly, the necessary code he refers to is not pieces of code but a complete code, nobody is asking him for the code of his project but to create an MCVE. *Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: I've already got bored in asking you for an MCVE, if you do, you let me know. ;)

Comment: I have included enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem, though. What is missing?
Btw I've got to go soon, I won't be able to continue this for a bit.

Comment: Goodbye, I'm leaving too, do you think that by copying the code that shows in your question, you can execute it without defining the missing variables? :)